# Apollo 11 first stage separation

Tags: apollo-11, launch-trajectories

Did Apollo 11 climb vertically upwards i.e. radially outwards, or "normal" to earth surface till it separated its first stage (approximately 38 Miles/60 Km or so..), or did it tilt at or before that altitude?

Answer (score 4):

This plot shows the pitch profile for a Saturn V from launch to Earth Parking Orbit and it's described like this:

> The vehicle rises nearly vertically from the pad, for approximately
> 450 feet, to clear the tower. During this period, a yaw maneuver is
> executed to provide tower clearance in the event of adverse wind
> conditions, deviation from nominal flight and/or engine failure.
>
> (See figure 2-1 for start and stop times for this and other maneuvers
> and events).
>
> After clearing the tower, a tilt and roll maneuver is initiated to
> achieve the flight attitude and proper orientation for the selected
> flight azimuth. Launch azimuth is 90 degrees; flight azimuth may vary
> between 72 and 108 degrees. The actual flight azimuth within this
> range is computed just prior to launch from a launch-day-dependent
> polynomial of launch azimuth as a function of launch time. From the
> end of the tilt maneuver to tilt-arrest, the pitch program provides a
> near-zero-lift trajectory that satisfies vehicle performance, heating
> and loads requirements. Tilt-arrest freezes the pitch attitude to
> dampen out pitch rates prior to S-IC/S-II separation. The pitch
> attitude remains constant until initiation of the Iterative Guidance
> Mode (IGM) which occurs during the S-II stage flight.

[image]

From [SA-507 Flight Manual](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/pdf/a12_sa507-flightmanual.pdf)

> .. the first figure gives you the best indication of those pitches, on
> page 2-4, **which looks like basically from 90° to 30° for the duration
> of the first stage burn**. Then it appears to hold that pitch for 30-45
> seconds while the second stage ignited and then the interstage was
> jettisoned. From there, looks like it pitched down at a pretty regular
> rate and hit about 0° by the time the second stage burnt out. Then it
> looks like during the third stage to achieve parking orbit it burnt at
> a negative pitch to maintain apogee while raising perigee to the right
> altitude.

from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/RealSolarSystem/comments/8a6ebd/saturn_v_pitch_rates/), emphasis mine